# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to return response in third party API based on HttpStatus

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am consuming a third party API and the returned response should be based on the Http Status

I am given these responses by the vendor:

**BadRequest:**

```
{
  "ResponseCode": "88",
  "ResponseDescription": "sample response"
}
```

SuccessRequest:

```
{
  "Token": "987654567873",
  "ExpiryDate": "2023-04-01T14:15:22Z",
  "ResponseCode": "00",
  "ResponseDescription": "sample response"
}
```

So in order to achieve the goal, I have these DTOs:

**StudentRequestDto:**

```
public class StudentRequestDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StudentCode { get; set; }
}
```

**BadRequestDto**

```
public class BadRequestDto
{
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**SuccessRequestDto**

```
public class SuccessRequestDto
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**GenericResponse**

```
public class GenericResponse
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}
```

So I have the implementation here:

```
    public async Task<SuccessRequestDto> RegisterStudent(StudentRequestDto payload)
    {
        var response = new SuccessRequestDto();
        var badResponse = new BadRequestDto();
        _genericResponse = new GenericResponse();
        try
        {
            _tokenService = new TokenService(_tokenHelper, MemoryCache, _tokenLogger);
            string defaultToken = await _tokenResetService.GenerateToken();

            var defaultHeaderInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            defaultHeaderInfo.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {defaultToken}");
            _genericResponse = await _myHelper.StudentTokenGen(defaultHeaderInfo, payload);
            if (_genericResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || _genericResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuccessRequestDto>(_genericResponse.ResponseMessage);
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuccessRequestDto>(_genericResponse.ResponseMessage);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

As I earlier stated I am sending the request to third party and in return get the response.

What I have I want to achieve is that if successful it should return SuccessRequestDto else it should return BadRequestDto.

How do I re-write the code to achieve this?

Comment: What is the problem? what is wrong with the code you have already?

Answer (score 0):

As far as we can see there is only a response object. whether it is a Success response or failed response depends on the ResponseCode.

#### ResponseDto

```cs
public class ResponseDto
{
    public string ResponseCode {get;set;}
    public string ResponseDescription {get;set;}
    public string? Token {get;set;}
    public DateTime? ExpiryDate {get;set;}

    // only if needed -> bool or enum
    public bool Success => ResponseCode == "00";
}
```

and you can decide what you want to do with the response outside this Api Handler, based on the Success bool or enum.

The Other solution you can try is to use `Func` to perform different operation based on the response, so you don't have to return any object back to the caller.